# How would the Ancient Greek noun λόρδων decline, and is the LSJ's definition of it correct?

Tags: terminology, ancient-greek, declension

I'm very familiar with Latin declensions, and have the resources necessary for that, but I have found nothing for Ancient Greek that I am able to make use of, especially considering my lack of understanding of how to use the few dictionaries that there are for word declension. The LSJ's entry for it is *ωνος, ὁ,*, though perseus.tufts.edu lists the LSJ entry as *λόρδ-ων , ωνος, ὁ,*. I already know my way around noun cases, so I don't need an explanation of those.
As for the definition, the LSJ says that means "the demon of impure", but I can find no other source to back that up, though I can find very few sources in general, since my search queries continuously returned results for the verb *λορδός*.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, and I will change the tags if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the LSJ entries are correct (and I don’t see why they shouldn’t be – they generally are), it would be declined… exactly as it says. Nom.sg. would be _λόρδων_, acc.sg. _λόρδω(να)_, gen.sg. _λόρδωνος_, dat.sg. _λόρδωνι_, voc.sg. _λόρδον_; nom.pl. _λόρδωνες_, acc.pl. _λόρδωνας_, gen.pl. _λορδώνων_, dat.pl. _λόρδωσι_. But a simple lookup of Greek declension types could tell you that, so what is the actual question, then? (Also _λοδρός_ isn’t a verb, did you mean to write _λορδόω_.)

Comment: the LSJ and Perseus entries look entirely consistent to me. For resources on Greek denclensions, the wikipedia page for "ancient greek nouns" has tables for the relevant noun classes. In this case it mostly looks like a double stem in on, with the length on the o outside the nominative singular either being generalised by analogy, or due to contraction with an underlying stem-final a

Answer (score 3):

These are two different words: first the first/second declension adjective λορδός ή, όν, “bent backward”, and second the third declension noun which LSJ cites as “λόρδων ωνος, ὁ, the demon of impure λόρδωσις”, or as Pape puts it less euphemistically: “λορδών , ῶνος, ὁ , ein komisch fingirter Dämon, von λορδόω , in obscönem Sinne”. Note the disagreement concerning the accent. λoρδων (ignoring the accent) could be gen. pl. of the former or nom. sing. of the latter.

Edit: I see now that both Pape and Bailly take λορδός to mean “bent forward”, not “backward”. This would ascribe a rather more drastic activity to the demon in question.

Answer (score 1):

Some attention is needed in regards to where the intonation goes, it should be ***λορδῶν*** (genitive plural of *λορδός*, bent), instead of ***λόρδων*** (modern Greek genitive plural of *λόρδος*, a translation of the English word *lords*).

Given the above, the plural male declension would be: ***λορδοί, λορδῶν, λορδοῖς, λορδούς, λορδοί***. Full details can be found in the inflection section at the [Wiktionary page for λορδός](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%B4%CF%8C%CF%82), where it has *λορδοῦ* instead of LSJ's *λόρδωνος*, and the Wiktionary version is entirely consistent with the standard o-declension of Greek nouns.